# Tmux eclipsed colorized output of ls

Tags: ls, tmux, xterm

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04, and when I use the Terminal I get colored filenames from `ls`. But inside tmux, everything ls prints is white. I know my tmux supports color, though, because I get color syntax highlighting when I run vim. My ~/.tmux.conf has this line already:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Here are some environment variables (from within tmux):

```
$ env | grep COLOR
LS_COLORS=di=34:ow=34
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

How can I get ls to show me color when inside tmux?

Comment: Your `LS_COLORS` is a bit sparse.  Try `eval "$(dircolors)"`.

Comment: Post the output of `type ls` when inside tmux.

Comment: Yes, or `dircolors -p > clrdb.txt` (`-p` is `--print-database`) and then examine it peace and quiet. If you find patterns that apply to the files you are listing, as well as (for example) the `--color=always` option (would be a fair bet) on `type ls` (as mentioned), and still no colors, ls shouldn't be where the shoe hurts. If you have an alias or anything that blocks ls, try `\ls` and give the color option explicitly.

Comment: `type ls` gives `ls is /bin/ls`, and after saying `source ~/.bashrc` it gives `ls is aliased to 'ls --color=auto'`, so the problem was I wasn't sourcing `~/.bashrc`. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` don't outputs colors by default, usually it is an alias to `ls --color=auto` setted in `.bashrc`. Check if you're invoking `ls` directly or through an alias with `type ls`.

If it outputs `ls is /bin/ls` maybe your `.bashrc` wasn't loaded when you created the `tmux` session. If so, try to reload it with `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yep, looks like the problem was that I wasn't sourcing `~/.bashrc`. Could have sworn I checked that... :-) Thanks!

Comment: Funny, sometimes we're looking far away but the answer is in front of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forcing tmux to colorize things by invoking it with **-2** as a parameter?

Comment: Did you mean `--color=always`? My `ls` didn't recognizes `-2`.

Comment: No, I meant -2 ... but as a parameter for tmux, not ls.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer. :-1

Comment: I was already running `tmux -2`, but that's good advice if anyone else has this problem.